# Pascal error with array

Tags: arrays, pascal

```
program s;
  type info = record
       name, surname: string;
       min, sec: integer;
  end;
  arrays = array[2..50] of info;

  var A: arrays;
begin
  A[1].name := 'name';
end.
```

What is wrong with that? It gives me range check error and I have no idea what is that.

Comment: On which line does it give you a range check?

Comment: And by the way, can somebody tell me, how Nick D made so nice edit?

Comment: You can see the edit by clicking on the link "edited X mins ago"; the edit replaced the individual apostrophes you had around each line with simple four-space indentation.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2844424/revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you an error because you are creating an array from indexes 2 to 50.

So the first element you can access would be 2.

```
begin
  A[2].name := 'name';
end.
```

A range check error means that you are trying to access an array in an invalid position (hence, out of range). Pascal, unlike other languages, throws a compilation error if you do this.